# EmojiCompat Flags not working on Marshmallow and above (but fine on older OS versions)

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm trying to display a flag as an emoji using the new `EmojiCompatTextView`. It works just fine for older Android versions, but on Marshmallow and above it shows a placeholder question mark flag. Here is the XML:

```
            <android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiAppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/opponent_flag"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                />
```

and the code to initialize the EmojiCompat (straight from the google docs):

```
val config: EmojiCompat.Config
// Use a downloadable font for EmojiCompat
val fontRequest = FontRequest(
        "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
        "com.google.android.gms",
        "Noto Color Emoji Compat",
        R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs)
config = FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig(applicationContext, fontRequest)
        .setReplaceAll(true)
        .registerInitCallback(object : EmojiCompat.InitCallback() {
            override fun onInitialized() {
                Log.i(TAG, "EmojiCompat initialized")
            }

            override fun onFailed(@Nullable throwable: Throwable?) {
                Log.e(TAG, "EmojiCompat initialization failed", throwable)
            }
        })
EmojiCompat.init(config)
```

I get the message `EmojiCompat initialized` in the log and in fact all other emojis I tried work except the flags.

Screenshots below for Lollipop and Nougat showing how it should work and how it doesn't:
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a bug, recently claimed fixed by Google but indications are otherwise, unfortunately.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72084134

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. Your code works as expected. Try to remove code below to fix your issue

```
        .setReplaceAll(true)
```

Comment: bah! it *kinda* works in that the flags now show on Marshmallow, but they don't look like the ones in the Noto font (e.g. the Oreo one) hence you lose the consistency... still useful as a workaround until Google decides to finally fix this?

Comment: Worked for me at Nexus 5X with Android v.8.1